# find the exact value of $\cos^2x$ and $\csc x$.

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $x=\tan ^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$, find the exact value of $\cos^2x$ and $\csc x$.

How to find this without using calculator?

Comment: Construct a right triangle where one of the other angles has a tangent value of $ \ \frac{1}{3} \ $ , for instance, with a vertical leg of $ \ 1 \ $ and a horizontal leg of $ \ 3 \ $ .

Comment: $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, $tan(x)=\frac{1}{3}$. Since tangent is positive and we are immediately limited to the fourth and first quadrants we conclude that $x$ must lie in the first quadrant, where each trigonometric function is positive.

Comment: Look up identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that: $x = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\Rightarrow \tan x = \dfrac{1}{3}, \text{ and } x \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\Rightarrow \cos x > 0 \Rightarrow  \sin x > 0\Rightarrow \csc x > 0\Rightarrow \tan^2 x = \dfrac{1}{9}\Rightarrow \sec^2 x = 1+ \tan^2 x = 1+\dfrac{1}{9} = \dfrac{10}{9}\Rightarrow \cos ^2 x = \dfrac{1}{\sec^2 x} = \dfrac{9}{10}\Rightarrow \sin^2 x = 1- \cos ^2x = 1- \dfrac{9}{10} = \dfrac{1}{10}\Rightarrow \sin x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{10}$